# Firestore add data to the two collections

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried to add data to the firestore collection as shown below.

This is the data structure of it. I have manually added the fields like below just for a demo to show the data structure which I want.

*Part 1*

[image]

*Part 2*

[image]

I have tried with below code. But it creates 2 project docs. One has project details and other has only the budgets(i.e. it doesn't have any project details). But I need only one `project` doc and `budgets` as its collection. Can you tell me how to do that?

```
 async create(data: ProjectDetail) {
    try {
      this.projectCollectionRef = this.fireStore.collection(`userProfile/${this.userId}/projects`);
      const projectId = this.fireStore.createId();
      const project: ProjectDetail = {
        id: projectId,
        name: data.name,
        completionDate: data.completionDate,
        isArchived: data.isArchived,
        creationTime: moment().format(),
      };
      await this.projectCollectionRef.add(project);

      this.budgetCollectionRef = this.fireStore.collection(`userProfile/${this.userId}/projects/${projectId}/budgets`);
      forEach(data.budgetList, (value: Budget) => {
        const budgetId = this.fireStore.createId();
        const budget: Budget = {
          id: budgetId,
          amount: value.amount,
          contingency: value.contingency,
          budgetGroup: value.budgetGroup
        };
        this.budgetCollectionRef.add(budget);
      });
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

When I used above code it creates like below:

[image]

[image]